# MVC Entity Framework connection string references other project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm doing a Model first approach for a Microsoft MVC application. The solution is named "TutorialPile" divided into two projects, Domain and WebUI. I try to add a controller for the Tutorial object to the WebUI project, and I select the domain class and the DB context. However, I get the error, "Unable to retrieve metadata for TutorialPile.Tutorial. Unable to load the specified metadata resource."

Looking around online it looks like it can't find the edmx object in the connection string in the web.config file. I copied the connection string from the Domain project's app.config file but it still doesn't work. Here are the connection strings from the web.config file.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"         connectionString="data   source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="TutorialPileModelContainer"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TutorialPileModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TutorialPileModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TutorialPileModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TutorialPileDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="TutorialPileDbContext"       connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TutorialPileModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TutorialPileModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TutorialPileModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TutorialPileDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And here is the connection string that I copied.

```
<add name="TutorialPileDBEntities"      connectionString="metadata=res://*/TutorialPile.csdl|res://*/TutorialPile.ssdl|res://*/TutorialPile.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=TutorialPileDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any ideas on what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure...

1. the edmx file's build action is set to EntityDeploy (select the file and go to the properties window).
2. Your WebUI project references the Domain project
3. Edit the connection string on your WebUI project to reference the metadata from the other project. Using * means it can come from any dll. BUT, if your edmx file is inside a folder, you have to map the hierarchy.

Eg:
**Path to EDMX:** TutorialPile.Domain/Model/TutorialPile.edmx
**Connection string:** res://*/Model.TutorialPile.csdl|res://*/Model.TutorialPile.ssdl|res://*/Model.TutorialPile.msl

Even better:

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) suggests you specify the assembly (for performance reasons) using the full name of the assembly (something like: AdventureWorks, 1.0.0.0, neutral, a14f3033def15840). I couldn't make it work. But, using only the name of the assembly works for me. So, if your domain project outputs a TutotialPile.Domain.dll, you can use:

res://TutorialPile.Domain/Model.TutorialPile.csdl|res://TutorialPile.Domain/Model.TutorialPile.ssdl|res://TutorialPile.Domain/Model.TutorialPile.msl